# How to filter a sets of paths to avoid repeat them using AWK?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

Is there a way to get the last full path from a list and
avoid the middle part and just get long path instead of 
the beginning and central part?

Input:

```
Data
Output
Output\Results
Output\Results\head
Output\Results\head\main
Output\Results\footer
```

Output:

```
Data
Output\Results\head\main
Output\Results\footer
```

Comment: Your desired output is a bit confusing. Why the second line is `Output\Results\head\main`, not `Output\Results\head\main\index.html`?

Comment: you were right, Since I'm just getting the paths, I erased the index.html

Answer (score 2):

As @tshiono pointed out in the comment above, your requirements are somewhat vague ... if order is important my solution **won't** work for you.

```
$ cat file
Data
Output
Output\Results
Output\Results\head
Output\Results\head\main\index.html
Output\Results\footer
```

And a bit of awkward `awk`:

```
$ <file LC_ALL=C sort | awk 'BEGIN{x=""} {split( $0, a, "\\" );b=a[1]; for(i=2; i<=length(a) ; i++) {if(a[i]!~/\./){b=b "\\" a[i]};$0=b}; ; if(!index($0,x)){print x};x=$0}END{print x'
Data
Output\Results\footer
Output\Results\head\main
```

Edit 1:
The changed input simplifies the awk greatly (while the original still works):

```
<file LC_ALL=C sort | awk 'BEGIN{x=""} {if(!index($0,x)){print x};x=$0}END{print x}'
Data
Output\Results\footer
Output\Results\head\main
```

Comment: Since I'm just getting the paths, I erased the index.html

Comment: So - does it (either the original or the new, shortened version) match your needs?